# How to access Sharepoint from Salesforce

Tags: integration, contentdocument

How to access sharepoint links,docs etc... from salesforce and I'm not looking to upload anything to sharepoint via salesforce but looking to access the sharepoint data from salesforce.

What are the options I have? I have looked online and there is not much info about this and also i'm not looking to buy any appexchange.

Answer (score 1):

`Files Connect` is a built in solution. From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_connect_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US), and the [implementation guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_files_connect_implementation.pdf)

**First, enable Files Connect, and let users access related external data sources**

- Enable Salesforce Files Connect for Your Organization.
- Let Users and Administrators Access Files Connect Data Sources.

**For cloud-based data sources, create an authentication provider, and then define the source**

...

If you use Microsoft’s cloud systems:

- Create an Authentication Provider for SharePoint Online Using Azure (Preferred Method).
- Define an External Data Source for SharePoint Online or OneDrive for Business.

...

**For on-premises data sources, set up a Secure Agent, and then define the source**

> Note:
>   This process requires a paid permission set license, “Files Connect for on-premises external data sources.” For information about permission set licenses, see Salesforce Help.

- Set Up a Secure Agent for SharePoint 2010 or 2013 on a Linux or Windows server to securely connect Salesforce to data stored behind your firewall.
- Define an External Data Source for SharePoint 2010 or 2013.

**Include the external data in global search**

To let users access external data in global Salesforce searches, you’ll need to create an external object and give users access to its fields. This is an optional step, but highly recommended to best integrate external data with Salesforce.

**For per-user data sources, have users authenticate in Salesforce**

If you specified per-user authentication for a data source and exposed it through profiles or permission sets, ask authorized users to provide their data source credentials.

**Start accessing, sharing, and searching external files!**

Now users can access and share external files via the Files tab and feed, and search for them right alongside their Salesforce content

Comment: We are planning to use File Connect and setup all configuration as per the salesforce_files_connect_implementation guide. When validating "External Data Source" getting this error message. "We can’t log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
Remote_Error: server_error".  Is this error message make sense, not sure what to check. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you do, you're looking at an integration of some kind that's going to cost you money. Since you don't want to import the data, the way to go would seem to be to use ODATA External Objects (it's also been referred to as Lightning Connect and various other things) to access the data.

You could either use the Salesforce connector that's available or write your own. Regardless of who's connector you use, it's going to cost you to pay for the integration that's required to make the web services connection and I believe that Salesforce will also charge you for the service if you use their connector. If you don't, you'll at least pay for the API usage. You'll need to discuss the particulars with your Account Rep.

Comment: Is there away to use web services or oAuth to connect sharepoint from salesforce without going through connect

Comment: Files Connect is free, just needs a remote data source connection and a remote object (the SharePoint files).

Comment: Nick, I'm not entirely certain how the licensing works on that. That's why I mentioned that there are 3rd party connectors that others have written. @MohithShrivastava did one that he's written about on his blog that may also be on Github. Again, you'll want to speak to your Account Rep because you'll still be using API calls.

Comment: Make that free if you use SharePoint cloud service.